# Servidor casero XAMPP + IP pública con certificado SSL valido

Tags: xampp, ssl

Tengo un servidor casero con xampp el cual tiene una IP pública con la cual puedo acceder a él desde cualquier sitio, pero este tiene una conexión no segura, mi pregunta es como puedo instalar un certificado SSL valido para que sea segura la conexión desde internet?
Al usar http://190.85.19.54 entra normal pero necesito https

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero, debes generar un dominio.
Puedes comprar un .com .net ... o crear uno gratuito .ml .ga .tk ...
https://my.freenom.com

Después en caso de tener una ip dinámica, debes usar un servidor ddns para cuando tu proveedor de internet (isp) te cambie la ip, se actualice la resolución de nombre de dominio a la nueva ip.

- https://ydns.io/
- https://freedns.afraid.org/
- https://www.securepoint.de/en/products/nextgen-utm-firewalls/securepoint-dyndns.html
- https://duckdns.org/
- https://www.noip.com/remote-access

Después debes crear el certificado. Puedes hacerlo también de forma gratuita con [certbot](/questions/tagged/certbot) y [letsencrypt](/questions/tagged/letsencrypt).

Aquí un artículo muy bueno explicando este último paso:
https://tecadmin.net/install-lets-encrypt-create-ssl-ubuntu/

El resultado será algo como:
https://phishingoda.ga
Pincha en el candado verde para ver los certificados.

Aquí puedes ver más detalles:
https://observatory.mozilla.org/analyze/phishingoda.ga

A tener en cuenta.

- Cuando pones tu servidor en la red de tu casa accesible públicamente (internet), va a ser atacado.
- Si la red de tu casa no está correctamente configurada, alguien que hacke tu servidor podrá pivotar o intentar ataques contra tu router u otros equipos de la red.

Te dejo varios artículos que te puedan ser de utilidad:

- https://geekflare.com/apache-web-server-hardening-security
- https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/faq-detail/49564.htm
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-security-best-practices-tutorial.html
- https://howtogetonline.com/how-to-harden-your-php-for-better-security.php
- https://www.manageengine.com/vulnerability-management/misconfiguration/windows-firewall/how-to-close-port-135-udp-tcp-disabling-dcom-service-control-manager.html
- https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/articles/202720396-Security-risks-Netbios-port-exposure-remote-access-removal
- https://www.cyber.gov.au/acsc/view-all-content/publications/hardening-microsoft-windows-10-version-1909-workstations
- https://severalnines.com/database-blog/ten-tips-how-achieve-mysql-and-mariadb-security
- https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/firewall-security
- https://bugcrowd.com/vulnerability-rating-taxonomy
- https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/

Comment: Hola amigo voy a intentar realizar, no había pensado en agregar un dominio actualmente tengo ip publica fija pero al conexión no es segura